# Windows 7 Start Menu Search Box missing

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have restarted my windows 7 ultimate x32 OS for couple of times and i still cannot see searchbox in my start menu. I searched it little bit and i applied this solution but it still doesn't appear.

Right click on the task bar and select properties, click on the start menu tab and then click on customize. At the bottom you'll see a button that says default settings, click that and it'll set everything in the start menu back to default.

How can i fix it?

This is my start menu:

[image]

And this is how it suppose to be:

[image]

Comment: Its very likely a program you installed removed the functionality.  I would use your restore points to figure out what program that is.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. it was ok yesterday when i left the office. But when i came back in morning searchbox was gone. The computer is used for software test operations but nothing installed in last 2 days. Only interactions with a possible new program was running some binaries which was run before. And i didn't see any problem earlier

Comment: So this is a company pc...Why don't you just restore its default configuration from a backup?

Comment: @Ramhound , i did and it still not working

Comment: If the default configuration backup doesn't have it then your backups are corrupt and should be replaced.

Comment: If this is a work pc, then it might be a Group Policy, talk to your system admins.  It might be accidental or on purpose!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone (or something) must have disabled the Windows Search feature on you PC.

---

### To enable it back, do the following:

1. Open `Control Panel`
2. Find `Programs and Features` 
   [image]
3. In the left panel look for `Turn Windows features On or Off`[image]
4. Scroll down the list and look for `Windows Search` and check the box[image]
5. Click OK and then Yes on the Window[image]
6. Restart to complete the change and you should find the Search on Start menu

---

Comment: All i see is "Internet Explorer 9" in the list

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım Open up command-prompt and type `sfc.exe /scannow`. Try the steps I mentioned again after the scan is complete.

Comment: it asks me to type command number? :s

Comment: Weird. Can you upload a screenshot of what you get?

Comment: Hi, instead of strugling eith that i format the computer :D
but thanks for your help :)